# How to handle Exceptions for a Custom Filter FORM_LOGIN_FILTER

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, exceptionhandler

I have a custom Filter that validates a Token, tokenLoginFilter

**my Spring Security xml**

```
<http pattern="/api/**" use-expressions="true" create-session="stateless" entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
    <custom-filter ref="tokenLoginFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
    <!--<form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="mySuccessHandler" authentication-failure-handler-ref="myFailureHandler" />
    <logout />-->
    <intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/api/login/**" access="permitAll"/>
</http>
```

**TokenLoginFilter**

```
@Component
public class TokenLoginFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
    public static final String DEFAULT_TOKEN_AUTHENTICATION_PARAMETER_NAME = "token";

    @Autowired
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                         FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String[] parameters = request.getParameterValues(DEFAULT_TOKEN_AUTHENTICATION_PARAMETER_NAME);

        if (parameters != null && parameters.length > 0) {
            String token = parameters[0];

            if (token != null && !token.isEmpty()) {
                TemporaryAuthenticationToken temporaryAuthenticationToken = new TemporaryAuthenticationToken(token);
                temporaryAuthenticationToken.setDetails(
                        new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails((HttpServletRequest) request));

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(
                        authenticationManager.authenticate(temporaryAuthenticationToken));
            }
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

In the authenticationManager.authenticate call, I throw a **BadCredentialsException** from my **TokenAuthenticationProvider**

**TokenAuthenticationProvider**

```
@Component
public class TokenAuthenticationProvider extends AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider {
    public static final TimeZone DEFAULT_TIME_ZONE = getTimeZone("UTC");

    @Autowired
    protected TemporaryAuthenticationTicketService temporaryAuthenticationTicketService;

    @Autowired
    protected UsersService usersService;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        if (authentication instanceof TemporaryAuthenticationToken) {
            TemporaryAuthenticationTicket temporaryAuthenticationTicket = null;
            try {
                temporaryAuthenticationTicket = temporaryAuthenticationTicketService.find(
                        ((TemporaryAuthenticationToken) authentication).getCredentials());
            } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException ignored) {
            }

            if (temporaryAuthenticationTicket != null) {
                Calendar expirationDate = Calendar.getInstance(DEFAULT_TIME_ZONE);
                expirationDate.setTime(temporaryAuthenticationTicket.getExpirationDate());

                if (Calendar.getInstance(DEFAULT_TIME_ZONE).before(expirationDate)) {
                    Users users = usersService.findUsersUnsecure(temporaryAuthenticationTicket.getUserId());

                    if (users != null) {
                        UserDetails userDetails = new User(users);

                        return createSuccessAuthentication(userDetails, authentication, userDetails);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                throw new BadCredentialsException(messages.getMessage(
                        "AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials", "Bad credentials"));
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return TemporaryAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
    }

    @Override
    protected void additionalAuthenticationChecks(UserDetails userDetails,
                                                  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication)
            throws AuthenticationException {
    }

    @Override
    protected UserDetails retrieveUser(String username, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This **BadCredentialsException** is being interpreted as a error code 500 by Tomcat.

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Connection: close
Content-Language: en
Content-Length: 3152
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 08 Jul 2014 17:37:55 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1

<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.50 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {fon
t-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:
22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525
D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;backgro
und-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;col
or:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:w
hite;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;backgroun
d:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR
{color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 500 - Bad credentials
</h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Exception report</p><p><b>mes
sage</b> <u>Bad credentials</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The server encounter
ed an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</u></p><p><
b>exception</b> <pre>org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsE
xception: Bad credentials
        com.neptune.unsub.security.TokenAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(Toke
nAuthenticationProvider.java:56)
        org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate
(ProviderManager.java:156)
        com.neptune.unsub.security.TokenLoginFilter.doFilter(TokenLoginFilter.ja
va:38)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doF
ilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIn
tegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
        org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequ
estFilter.java:106)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doF
ilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilte
r.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doF
ilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(Filte
rChainProxy.java:192)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainPr
oxy.java:160)
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(Dele
gatingFilterProxy.java:343)
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(Delegating
FilterProxy.java:260)
        org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(H
iddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
        org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequ
estFilter.java:106)
        org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(
CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
        org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequ
estFilter.java:106)
        com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:169)
        com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:232)
</pre></p><p><b>note</b> <u>The full stack trace of the root cause is available
in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.50 logs.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apac
he Tomcat/7.0.50</h3></body></html>
```

I have tried using the Spring MVC way of handling exceptions

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandlers extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(BadCredentialsException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> badCredentialsException(BadCredentialsException e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getMessage(), UNAUTHORIZED);
    }


}
```

But the exception is not being handled by this ExceptionHandler. How can I get Spring to intercept this Exception before Tomcat handles it?

Comment: What does your TokenAuthenticationProvider look like?

Comment: I've updated to add my TokenAuthenticationProvider

Comment: If you are allowed to redirect the user to a new page, use values in the web.xml to redirect the user to error page on exception. <error-page/>

Comment: Line 56 is the throw new BadCredentialsException

Comment: @Zeus that won't really work for me. I'm using Spring MVC as a Rest server. So I need to return a proper HTTP status code

Answer (score 1):

You can try catching the exception in the doFilter method and handle it via an class that implements AuthenticationFailureHandler. The code should return a proper HTTP Status code along with a suitable Exception in a JSON format.

```
 @Override
public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, 
  HttpServletResponse response,AuthenticationException exception) throws 
  IOException, ServletException {
            response.setContentType( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);

             ApiError authenticationError = new ApiError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, exception.getMessage(), "Not Authenticated");
             ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
             response.getWriter().write(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(authenticationError));
};
```

**ApiError** is a custom class that contains the required fields to return an Exception scenario with proper Status Code and the exception message string.

**Side Note**

Your **GlobalExceptionHandlers** class won't work because those are annotated with ControllerAdvice, meaning any exception thrown from Controllers are handled there.